# Remove the line between the caption and the table

Tags: tables, floats

I try to draw a table by using the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{sigplanconf}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    A \\
    B \\
    C \\
    D \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And the table is printed as follows (please ignore the brown background of letters).

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to delete the line between the caption and the table?

Comment: Please add a MWE. The standard setup produces no rule.

Comment: I just added a MWE...

Comment: You're using a specialized class for submissions; if they want the rule, leave it.

Comment: But I do need to save some space by removing the line, I see this tips used in many papers (of this category of submission).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See page 17 of the "[Author’s Guide to the ACM SIGPLAN Class](http://drupal.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/sigplanconf-guide.pdf)":

```
\nocaptionrule \caption{ . . . }
```

The `\nocaptionrule` prefix on the `\caption` command suppresses the rule
above the caption.

So, I think the following is what you expected.

```
\documentclass[]{sigplanconf}
\begin{document}
\nocaptionrule
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|}
    \hline
    A \\
    B \\
    C \\
    D \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As my TeX installation does not contain a sigplanconf.cls I choosed  [2013/07/02 v2.8 ACM SIGPLAN Proceedings] out of the many different versions in the web.